# getResource always returns null

Tags: java, resources

I am trying to get resource from jar file from my class. Tried all variants like:

#### Paths

```
filename = "/resource.txt";
filename = "resource.txt";
filename = "/com/package/resource.txt";
filename = "resources/resource.txt";
```

#### Class Loaders

```
MyClass.class.getResouce(filename);
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
getClass().getResource(filename);
```

(In total at least 12 combinations.)

All this does not work (`getResource` returns `null`). I saw many examples in internet, no example works for my project.

What can I do?

I use Oracle Java 1.7 and 1.6, JetBrains Idea 10.5.2, Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: Where **exactly** is the `resource.txt` that you are trying to load and how **exactly** is your classpath configured?

Comment: resource.txt is text file, I want use its content. When I execute my jar I use such command: @java -cp "%~dp0\myjar.jar" so classpath I think should be right. When I start in Idea it writes to console: -classpath "....;c:/my/project/folder;..."

Comment: Again: **Where exactly** is the `resource.txt`? Is it inside the jar? if so, then *where* inside the jar? If not, then *where* outside the jar?

Comment: filename is declared before getting resource. And resource I placed in root of jar, inside package with MyClass, inside package relative to MyClass.

Comment: @Dmitry - what is the result of running `jar tf myjar.jar`?

Comment: *"And resource I placed in root of jar, inside package with MyClass, inside package relative to MyClass."*  Am I seeing triple?  That sounds like 3 different places to me.  Please take McDowell's advice and add the output as an edit to the question.

Comment: O_O There is no resource.txt in files list that McDowell advised! How can it be?

Comment: Well, sounds like the jar file doesn't contain your `resource.txt` which would explain that you get `null` on `getResource()`. Now, how do you build that jar file?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I am using "build artifact" in Jetbrains Idea.

Comment: On Windows the file separator is not `/`, it's `\\`.